# Parse data from 2 log files in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I need to parse thread number, run number and test number from file1, match the test number in file2 and write both these values into a new file.

The first file has the following content:

```
com-0 thread-0 [ run-0, test-1201 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/metaBar_sprite.png -> 200 OK, 682 bytes
com-0 thread-0 [ run-0, test-1202 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/chattersupersprite.png?v=182-4 -> 200 OK, 40172 bytes
com-0 thread-0 [ run-0, test-1203 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/chatter/wtdNowGradientbg.png -> 200 OK, 201 bytes
com-0 thread-0 [ run-0, test-1204 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/chatter/wtdNowIcon_sprite.png -> 200 OK, 7280 bytes
com-0 thread-0 [ run-0, test-1205 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf/img/sprites/icons24.png -> 200 OK, 20287 bytes
com-0 thread-0 [ run-0, test-1206 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/feeds/follow_sprite.png -> 200 OK, 2894 bytes
```

The second file has the following content

```
1 Thread, Run, Test num, Start time, Test time, Errors, HTTP response code, EPQ
2 0, 0, 1201, 1370898725367, 154, 0, 200, 2049 
3 0, 0, 1202, 1370898725523, 505, 0, 204, 0
2 0, 0, 1201, 1370898725367, 400, 0, 200, 2049 
2 0, 0, 1201, 1370898725367, 1124, 0, 200, 2049 
3 0, 0, 1202, 1370898725523, 1405, 0, 204, 0
```

The desired output would be:

```
thread-0 [ run-0, test-1201 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/metaBar_sprite.png = [154, 400, 1124]
thread-0 [ run-0, test-1202 ]: https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/chattersupersprite.png?v=182-4 = [505, 1405]
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure how to compare data from one file to another in a dictionary or list format.I am very new to python. Please help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Load everything in sqlite first and then use SQL to mix/match records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of the two logs stays the same...

```
log1 = [line.replace(',', '').split() for line in open('test1.txt', 'r')][:]
log2 = [line.replace(',', '').split() for line in open('test2.txt', 'r')][1:]
log3 = [] # need for combining.
```

This will produce a list, split by  space, for each log file. Then it is a mater of matching up the keys with the data you need from each.

```
# First, get the tests from the second log.
tests = {}
for line in log2:
    test = line[3] # test number
    if test not in tests:
        tests[test] = {'times': []}

    tests[test]['times'].append(line[5]) # test time
```

Next, you want to check against the first log by each test number:

```
for line in log1:
    test = line[4].split('-')[1] # changes test-#### to ####
    if test in tests:
        tests[test].update({
            'thread': line[1],
            'run':    line[3],
            'url':    line[6],
            'times':  ', '.join(tests[test]['times'])
        })
```

Then, it's just a matter of putting the tests `dict` back together into a log file.

```
for key, test in tests.iteritems():

    line = '{thread} [ {run}, test-{key} ]: {url} = [{times}]\n'
    line = line.format(thread=test['thread'], run=test['run'], key=key,
        url=test['url'], times=test['times'])

    log3.append(line)

with open('log3.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(''.join(log3))
```